# using Fomik hook `useField` and `react-data-table-component` causes infinite loop

Tags: formik

I am using `react-data-table-component` inside `formik` form to update new values. But the problem is whenever the `MyTable` component is re-rendered, the `selectableRowSelected()` callback is called, which triggers `onSelectedRowsChange` event in which I use `helpers.setValue()` to set value, which then makes `MyTable` component renders again. This whole process causes infinite loop, and I still don't have a solution for this.

```
function MyTable() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [field, meta, helpers] = useField({ name: "use" });

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://reqres.in/api/users?page=1&per_page=3")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((res) => setData(res.data));
  }, []);

  const handleChange = React.useCallback(({ selectedRows }) => {
    let selectedIds = selectedRows.map(function (row) {
      return parseInt(row.id);
    });
    selectedIds.sort();
    console.log(" ~ selectedIds", selectedIds);
    // helpers.setValue(selectedIds, true); --> uncomment this will cause infinite loop.
  }, []);

  return (
    <DataTable
      title="User List"
      columns={columns}
      data={data}
      selectableRows
      selectableRowsHighlight
      onSelectedRowsChange={handleChange}
      selectableRowSelected={(row) => {
        return meta.value.includes(parseInt(row.id));
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-tu-l1pxvb?file=/src/MyTable.jsx:375-1249

Answer (score 0):

I think I've figured it out myself. But I will post it here in case anyone may encounter the same.

There is no way to stop this problem as the way RDT works is whenever `selectableRowSelected` is called, it will dispatch an action with `type: SELECT_MULTIPLE_ROWS`:

```
dispatch({
    type: 'SELECT_MULTIPLE_ROWS',...
});
```

then in `tableReducer`, it returns `toggleOnSelectedRowsChange` as `boolean` value:

```
case 'SELECT_MULTIPLE_ROWS': {
...
return {
    ...state,
    ...,
    toggleOnSelectedRowsChange,
};
```

which controls the trigger of `onSelectedRowsChange` event (as mentioned at comment in the source code):

```
useDidUpdateEffect(() => {
    onSelectedRowsChange({ allSelected, selectedCount, selectedRows: selectedRows.slice(0) });
    // onSelectedRowsChange trigger is controlled by toggleOnSelectedRowsChange state
}, [toggleOnSelectedRowsChange]);
```

Overall, solution for this problem is don't use formik with RDT for row selection, use another datatable lib.